# CKeditor Custome Plugin: Insert a span Without creating nested span

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I have written a custom Plugin in CKEditor which actually inserts a span over the selected text in the editor. Below is the code snippet I have used to achieve the same.

**HTML:**

```html
<p><span class="highlight"> This is a simple text with some words </span><p>
```

Suppose just "simple text" is selected in editor and the plugin button is pressed. Below code executes

**Plugin code**

```js
var style = new CKEDITOR.style( { element: 'span', attributes: { 'class': 'reader' } } );


editor.applyStyle( style );
```

**Output**

```html
<p><span class="highlight"> This is a <span class="reader">simple text</span> with some words </span></p>
```

However, this introduces nesting of spans. I want to avoid nesting of these spans. Instead the output is something like below which i expect.

**Expected Output**

```html
<p><span class="highlight"> This is a </span><span class="reader">simple text</span><span class="highlight"> This is a </span> with some words </span></p>
```

Inshort I want to avoid nesting of tags,
Before inserting a new span, 
1. end the previous span tag
2. insert the new span
3. continue the previous span after the inserted span. The good thing about inserting style in this way is I am always able to retain the format tags applied to the selection like

etc

Is there a way that can achieve the desired functionality?